# getting charconversion exception for " %" value in query parameter?

Tags: java, exception, parsing, parameters

i am getting adding some of parameter in query string.value of these param can be "a%%","%" etc.on java code side .while parsing query parameter  i m getting char conversionexception 
as shown below in exception log.

13:14:39,555 ERROR [STDERR] java.io.CharConversionException: EOF
  13:14:39,555 ERROR [STDERR]     at      org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.convert(UDecoder.java:119)
  13:14:39,555 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.convert(UDecoder.java:87)
   13:14:39,555 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters.processParameters(Paramete
 rs.java:428)
  13:14:39,555 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters.processParameters(Paramete
rs.java:515)
  13:14:39,555 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters.handleQueryParameters(Para
meters.java:298)
  :14:39,555 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.coyote.tomcat4.CoyoteRequest.parseRequestParameters(Co
yoteRequest.java:1933)

what should i do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like the query string being sent to your Java code is malformed. The percent sign is special in query strings: It introduces a two-digit hexadecimal number identifying a character. For instance, `%20` is a space. To put a percent sign in a query string correctly, one uses `%25` (character 25h is the percent sign in Unicode). If the query string you're processing really, literally has `%%` in it, then it is malformed and you'll want to have the side sending it fixed.

Edit: In your comment you say you're the one sending the invalid query string. To properly encode a query parameter, use the [`encodeURIComponent`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURIComponent.asp) JavaScript function:

```
var encodedValue;
encodedValue = encodeURIComponent(yourTextfield.value);
someurl = "http://example.com?x=" + encodedValue;
```

Comment: actually i am getting value of query parameter from a input textbox (searchinput).i am appending value of this textbox to query string by using jaavscript.so i need to have some way out to send value of this textbox even if it is "%".