# Properly encoding percent sign (%) in Apachi Http Client form post using UrlEncode

Tags: java

This seems like an extremely easy problem but alas I cannot figure it out nor find a solution anywhere else. I'm concatenating a string that has a % within and for some reason it adds the number 25 after the %. Anyone know of a solution to this easy problem?

```
String buttonCheck = "%26" + DATABASE.getValue("buttonCheck") + "%26";
```

Comes out to

```
"%2526value%2526"
```

EDIT: It has become apparent that the issue is actually within URL encoding and I will add more relevant data to the issue.

I am developing an Android App that parses HTML from a site and allows the user to interact with it through the Android UI. I am having an issue with encoding % into a parameter for a form.

```
public class CLASS extends Activity
{
     DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient;
     String url = "http://www.url.com"
     HttpRequestBase method = new HttpPost(url);
     List<NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
     nvps.add("buttoncheck", "%26" + DATABASE.getValue("buttonCheck") + "%26");
     //DATABASE is simply a class that handles a HashMap

     HttpPost methodPost = (HttpPost) method;
     methodPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, HTTP.UTF_8));
     execute(method);
}
```

Rather than sending the form value of

```
buttoncheck=%26value%26
```

I get

```
buttoncheck=%2526value%2526
```

Comment: can't reproduce. please give all the relevant code.

Comment: I don't know why it is that way right now but just wanted to point out that `%` is ASCII `0x25`.  So at least there it is related to something in the string.

Comment: @org.life.java I highly doubt that as the 25 comes out BEFORE 26. I could understand if it was after but that's not the case. DATABASE is just a class that has access methods to a Hash Map, nothing fancy. I then add buttonCheck into another Map that is used for HttpClient Posting. Ah I should also add that I read the string AFTER it is sent through the Http post. I'll look into that.

Comment: I think jon skeet's answer is reasonable .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apparently the string went through "percent-encoding" when it becomes part of a URI.

If that's the case, you should not do percent-encoding so early. instead

```
String buttonCheck = "&" + DATABASE.getValue("buttonCheck") + "&";
```

which will end up in the URI as

```
"%26value%26"
```

Comment: This is exactly what I found to be the issue after investigating how URLEncoding works. I was viewing the data that was sent from a browser.

Answer (score 5):

It won't come out as "%2526value%2526" in `buttonCheck`. I strongly suspect you're looking at a value later on - for example, after URI encoding. Work out what's doing that encoding, and what you *actually* want to be encoded.

Just to be clear, the 25 is completely distinct from the 26. You'll see the same thing if you get rid of the 26 completely, with

```
String buttonCheck = "%" + DATABASE.getValue("buttonCheck") + "%";
```

At that point I suspect you'll get

```
%25value%25
```

Basically something is just encoding the % as %25. For example, this would do it:

```
import java.net.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String input = "%value%";
        String encoded = URLEncoder.encode(input, "utf-8");
        System.out.println(encoded); // Prints %25value%25
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure how URLEncodedFormEntity works. methodPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, HTTP.UTF_8)); is the relevant code, with nvps being the BasicNameValuePair where buttonCheck is read from. I don't see where it would go wrong.

Comment: I added the relevant code to my OP. I believe you are correct with the issue. Know of a remedy?

Comment: @Alejandro: Is this using Apache HTTP Client? I'm afraid I haven't used that for a while. It's also not entirely clear what you're actually trying to achieve. I suggest you start a new question specifying very clearly what the bigger picture is, what code you're using etc. It would be ideal if you could put this in the form of a short but complete program which others could run.

Comment: Yes it is Apache HTTP Client. I will do just that, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420243/getting-charconversion-exception-for-value-in-query-parameter) question, I would guess that the literal `%` is being encoded to `%25` in your string.  Which explains the added `25`.  Without seeing relevant code, we won't be able to know why it gets there in the first place.

Comment: The question you posted does have the exact same issue but that is based off of javascript. I'm trying to find a solution on the apache site.